# HashMap<Date, Transaction> or List with Transaction (Date as field)?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I'm working on program where I manage accounts, trades, transactions (txs), wallets with different currencies and so on. I want to put a list of txs (sorted by Date) in my wallets, list of trades (every Trade has two Txs: in & out) sorted by Date.

The question I have is, which is the better way to go?
I just need the txs-history and trade-history for printing them out from old to new.

a)

HashMap in Wallet:

```
HashMap<Date, Transaction> txs;
```

HashMap in Account:

```
HashMap<Date, Trade> trades;
```

b)

Date object in Transaction included and List in Wallet:

```
LinkedList<Transaction> txs;
```

Date object in Trade included and List in Account:

```
LinkedList<Trade> trades;
```

Comment: HashMap isn't sorted.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought I could sort it by Key. Then I will go for LinkedList, thanks.

Comment: TreeMap is sorted by key. But the main question should be - if you are going to access elements by key or you only need sorting. If you only need sorting then you can have a separate type for Date+Transaction and Date+Trade and sort them in the list, or keep them in the sorted set (with sort order defined as using Date part of the pair).

Comment: Can you strictly guarantee date uniqueness? Regular map holds only one value per same key.

Comment: To add to my earlier rather brief comment, I would consider using an ArrayList as well since it's simple to use and it's sorted. And with streams and lambda functions it' easy to retrieve specific data.